# Website not showing files over secure connection (on subdomains)

Tags: https, cpanel, cloudflare

I've got this [website](http://test.mcpro.games).
I basically can't see pages on my subdomains with HTTPS, I can see them without HTTPS though; I've contacted both my SSL provider and my hosting provider both just recommended me to talk to the opposite and they had no idea

I've had this problem for over 3 months now. I have no idea how to fix it.

And to clarify one thing: In the DNS I tried a A and CNAME both had same results.

If Wanting To Test It Go Here: http://test.mcpro.games

## cPanel:

[image: cPanel]

## Cloudflare (DNS):

[image: Cloudflare (DNS)]

## Without HTTPS:

[image]

## With HTTPS:

[image]

## Certificate Validity:

[image]

Comment: It looks like a web server misconfiguration.   What kind of access do you have to the server?   VPS?  cPanel?

Comment: It's shared hosting, cPanel

Comment: You also tagged this as "cloudflare".   How does cloudflare figure into your setup?

Comment: A screenshot of your cPanel setup for this subdomain might help.

Comment: There is a screenshot of cpanel and cloudflare is my dns and ssl provider.. the image at 3:34AM is cpanel and the image At 3:37AM is cloudflare

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of variables that can cause this, mostly related to the virtualhost configuration on the webserver. Your hosting provider should be able to help you validate the virtualhost configuration outside of Cloudflare.

Do you have any origin certificates installed between Cloudflare and your hosting provider, or do you just have the single certificate installed at Cloudflare's level?

Another option would be to try skipping Cloudflare directly and install the certificate at your hosting provider.

Comment: its randomly working now, all subdomains are working on HTTPS again, no clue what happened because, I did not do anything. but, I will still answer what you asked even though it is months later, I got a dedicated certificate from cloudflare and installed it into the server via cPanel